# How to reconcile React's setState with using the URL as the single source of truth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, browser-history

In React's documentation they recommend generally abstaining from the use of `this.forceUpdate`, instead recommending to use `this.setState` whenever possible.

In my application I have a component that contains a slide-out pane. It has nested elements and clicking each item updates the URL in a different way. For example, I could navigate to the following URLs by clicking around in it:

```
site.com/posts/create
site.com/posts/read
site.com/posts/4895734
site.com/posts/5465462
site.com/messages/43455
site.com/messages/create
```

Clicking each of these items should update the component's view and display it differently based on the URL. However, just calling `window.history.pushState` to update the URL does not cause React to update (you need to call `setState` or `forceUpdate` for that).

As a result, I am unsure of how to proceed. I rather not duplicate the "source of truth" and mirror the URL in React's state variables, because then there is conflict over whether or not the URL should be used to determine the state versus the component's state variables. It seems better to have the URL be the single source of truth.

However, if this is the case, then every time I change the URL I would have to do `this.forceUpdate` or some no-op call like `this.setState({ asdf: 5 })`. This would certainly work, but React's documentation specifically warns about calling `forceUpdate` all over the place in the application.

Is there a better way?

Comment: are you using class or functional components

Comment: Class components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what routing configuration you have, but are you using the history package?
https://reactrouter.com/core/api/history

https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-dhawan-qf6ke?file=/src/App.js

That should mount/rerender on url changes, as well as give the ability to pass state through the router.

Edit:

Simplified version

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-cookies-pyhq6?file=/src/Router.js

Comment: No, I'm not using any routing libraries. I rather not import a dependency for this one, small aspect of my application. I'm curious, do you know how the library works? Like, internally: how does it re-render on URL changes?

Comment: Yes, its based on React context in combination with (I think) higher order components. I edited my answer with a new link demonstrating a simplified version using just context.